# .NET MVC Application - Azure Active Directory - Redirecting to LocalHost

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-active-directory

I have a .NET MVC applicatoin and I am trying to use Azure AD Authentication.

I create a new project and chose

- "Work or School Accounts"
- Cloud - Single Organiszation

At no time does it ask me for a redirect URL

I then click okay and it creates the solution (as well as registering it at Azure AD).

Problem is that when I login it alway redirects to a localhost address.

Even if I change the web.config to the correct URL of the app (as registed in IIS) it keeps redirecting.  When I log into Azure AD the app is listed as an Enterprise Application and I am unable to change the homepage URL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of "Enterprise Applications", you need to go to "App Registrations" in your Azure AD.

So navigate to Azure Protal > Azure AD > App Registrations > Find app registration for your application (you may need to change from "My apps" to "All apps"

Then make whatever changes you need:

1. You can change the home page under Settings > properties
2. Also, an important part is to add the required URL in Reply URLs as shown in screenshot below. Settings > Reply URLs

[image]

Comment: Got it thanks!  I had been on that app registration page before but needed to click on "All Applications" not "Owned Applications" - I guess because VS created it.